# django-contact-form how to use the form inside any template, without a new url?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have installed `django-contact-form`, and the default `url` to the form is `'contact/'`. But, I already have my own contact page, let's call it `'contact_us/'`, I wish to include the form inside `'contact_us/'`, using the `url` and view I already have for `'contact_us/'`.

The usual way to do that is by using `{% extends 'contact_us' %}`, but if I do this, and remove my original `'contact_us/'` url, it gives me an `ReverseError`.

The way I think that would be possible is if sent the `ContactFormView` (from `django-contact-form`) as context to `'contact_us/'`, but I think that's not possible because each view has it's own `url`.

I want to know a way to be able to put the form easily inside of any template. There's probably a simple way to do that and I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `ContactFormView` from the `contact_us` by:
1. By overriding the url

**urls.py**

```
from contact_form.views import ContactFormView
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
# ... other URL patterns for your site ...
url(r'^contact_us/$',
    ContactFormView.as_view(),
    name='contact_form'),
url(r'^contact_us/sent/$',
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact_form/contact_form_sent.html'),
    name='contact_form_sent'),
]
```

2. If you want to customize this view

In **views.py**

```
from contact_form.views import ContactFormView

class CustomContactFormView(ContactFormView):
    # Customize any function that you want to
    template_name = 'custom_template.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from views import CustomContactFormView

urlpatterns = [
# ... other URL patterns for your site ...
url(r'^contact_us/$',
    CustomContactFormView.as_view(),
    name='contact_form'),
]
```